# UI not getting upated inside QT designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

Recently I started learning QT framework for developing GUI applications* in C++. Till now everything was fine with QT creator but when I try to change the background color of an element using CSS style sheet the QT UI designer does not get updated. Moreover even while writing the code the QT doesn't detect my newly added controls to the screen. Here is a GIF to show this problem.

[image]

Also I am not sure if that's the way QT works but after adding an element on the form I am not able to access that element by its object name in code immediately unless I build it again

[image: Object name not accessible in code before building]

**Here is my QT details**

[image]

Forgive me if i went wrong somewhere or made any mistakes, I am a Visual Studio guy and am quite new with using QT.

**Note:** I am asking that second one because i have seen a lot of tutorial videos on QT widget where the object could be accessed immediately in code after adding it.

Also first time when I used it, it did work. But since then the designer doesn't get updated

Comment: You have to compile the application again

Comment: add `#include <QPushButton>` on *.cpp

Comment: But still why isnt my ui getting updated

Comment: In the first gif that shows I do not see that you have recompiled the project: close the application and press the "run" button

Comment: I have sir Compiled it sir

Comment: For me there is no evidence of what you point out, update your gif. If it does not work then report the bug to qt

Comment: Thanks a lot sir i will update the gif at the earliest

Comment: @eyllanesc Sir i have updated the GIF to make it more informative to you. Do you think it might be a bug

Answer (score 1):

It was pretty much easy. I just had to change  the border property to any value and immediately changes can be seen. It was because of the border  i guess that was causing the problem.

Here is a gif to show you that...
[image]

And regarding the issue of mainwindow.ui not matching with ui_mainwindow.h file the solution was pretty simple both the build directory and working directory contain the same file called ui_mainwindow.h Delete the one in  the working directory and bingo it works.

Thanks to  this QT forum's  post 
[[Solved] What would cause a mainwindow.ui file not to match with it ui_mainwindow.h file?](https://forum.qt.io/topic/3361/solved-what-would-cause-a-mainwindow-ui-file-not-to-match-with-it-ui_mainwindow-h-file)

Note: Whenever the project is built or run, the ui_*.h files will be generated again causing you to delete the files again and again. A solution for that is to add a makefile in the working directory that automatically deletes the ui_*.h files after building the project ( post build step ). Here are the steps for it.

**Step 1 :** Create a makefile called **deleteUI_header.mk** and add the following  code to it as shown in the figure below

[image: makefile]

**Step 2 :** Save the file in the working directory of the project.

[image]

**Step 3 :** Now  open the project in QT and click on the project tab in the left hand side. Under build settings->build step click on add build step->make

[image]

Now override **jom.exe** with **make** (ensure that make's location is present in PATH environment variable ) and provide the following make argument

**-f deleteUI_header.mk**

[image]

Now whenever you will build the project the ui header files generated will automatically be deleted.
`